# Nginx Load Balancing traffic directly from server to clients

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm trying to setup a Nginx Load Balancer that traffic goes directly to clients instead of going trough the load balancer.

```
upstream backend {  
    server backend1.example.com weight=5;  
    server backend2.example.com;  
    server backend3.example.com backup;  
}
```

All the tutorials I found out are using;

```
server { 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can archive what I'm looking for?

[Example what I want to achive here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGx8H.png)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The response has to be part of the same connection as the request, unless the client is listening for push. Can you please edit your question to clearly state what problem you're having and why exactly you want to do this.

Comment: Nginx doesn't sound like the correct tool for the job, as @Tim mentions. NginxPlus (their commercial product) does offer [Direct Server Return](https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/), which sounds like what you are looking for (to a point). Bear in mind the nginx docs do specifically mention "DSR is of limited use for TCP protocols, and NGINX Plus’ reverse‑proxy architecture precludes its use for TCP connections. "

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The TCP connection is between the client and the LB, not the client and the backend. The client and the backend quite literally know nothing about each other (from a network stack point of view) so they no mechanism to exchange data between them is available.

Comment: So, if thats not possible, how I would do that following example? 1. Client contacts Load balancer 1.2. Load balancer checks server load (either locally saved stats or checking remotely) 1.3 Load balancer responds to the Client with the least troubled host 2. Client contacts Host with Moved 301 status code 3. Host responds with the requested files [Example here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDowm.png

Comment: That's theoretically possible. You'd need to identify a load balancer that can do it, though. The question though is: why? 99.999% of load balanced environments operate with clients communicating through the load balancer. Why are you trying to avoid this?

Comment: You could do that, but you'd probably have to write a custom load balancer app. You'd have to keep track of server load, then return a 302 redirect (browser) or information about the server (rich client) to use to the client. You'd need a REALLY good reason to do this over using a standard load balancer though.